# What does calloc that takes an assignment operator for size_t n do?

Tags: c, calloc

I am just checking out some leetcode submissions and came across this assignment for the 2sum soution:

```c
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int* res = calloc((*returnSize = 2), sizeof(int));
    ...
}
```

Is this saying "res is a pointer to an integer block of memory storing 2 int types initialised to 0" ? So the equivalent of:

```c
int* res = calloc(2, sizeof(int));
```

Or is it something else?

Comment: It's the same as `*returnSize = 2; int* res = calloc(*returnSize, sizeof(int));`

Comment: ...except that the pointer is only dereferenced once. The result of an assignment operation is the value that was assigned.

Comment: So, more correctly, `*returnSize = 2; int* res = calloc(2, sizeof(int));`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: “Was assigned” is ambiguous phrasing. Some people might say that 3.5 was assigned in `x = 3.5`, even if `x` has type `int` and has value 3 after the assignment. The value of an assignment expression is “the value of the left operand after the assignment” (C 2018 6.5.16 3).

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Those people would be incorrect. :-D 3.5 was the value of the right-hand operand, but not the value that was assigned (past tense), not "the value that was used to do the assigment." Still, though, that phrasing is (obviously) better. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't "taking an assignment operator for size_t" exactly. Rather, it's taking the result of the assignment operation for size_t.

For example

`(a = 2)`

Puts the value 2 in a **and** returns that assigned value. So you could also do something like:

```
int a, b;
b = (a = 2);
```

Here, `b` would get the result of the operation `(a = 2)`, which is 2.

That's what's happening in your case. The first argument passed to `calloc` is the result of the assignment `(*returnSize = 2)`, which is 2.